# Кнопка перехода на внешнюю ссылку

Tags: html

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой: 
на сайте сделал новую кнопку. При нажатии должно перекидывать на другой сайт. В админке всё сделали, но почему-то не хочет перебрасывать. Вот HTML-код:

```
<p><a title="Лицензионное ПО" onclick="window.open('http://comfy.ua/computer/software.html','','location=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,dependent=yes');return false;" href="/http://comfy.ua/computer/software.html">Soft </a></p>
```

На сайте кнопки уже есть, но все "внутренние", внешних пока не делал. 
Пробовал прописывать без href и onclick, без резалта. 
Причём, сама ссылка не меняется - всё равно сначала "вылезает" наш сайт (http://it-service.comfy.ua/ru), а потом тот, на который хотим перейти и после нажатия перекидывает на главную страницу. 
Пытаюсь разобраться - это проблема сайта либо в кривых руках, так как в программировании полный чайник. 
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Еще один умник... Не беритесь редактировать, ТС думает что его вопрос в таком виде лучше читаем! ТС, удачи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTFM](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

```
<a title="Лицензионное ПО" href="http://comfy.ua/computer/software.html" target="_blank">Soft</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Видимо, всё же проблема в стартовом сайте, так как код работает везде, но только не там, где хочется.